# How to configure slf4j in groovy

Tags: logging, groovy, slf4j

In a Java/Groovy application the following log4j pattern:

```
[%d{ISO8601}] [%-5p] [%l] - %m%n
```

produces correct output from the Java classes, but when the logger is called from a Groovy class, instead of the name of the calling class I get:

```
[org.slf4j.Logger$debug.call(?:?)]
```

P.S., I am not using the `@Slf4j` annotation, which seems to produce the same result.
How should this be addressed?

Comment: See if this is helpful - https://springframework.guru/logback-configuration-using-groovy/

Comment: This is certainly interesting but I need to resolve the problem with log4j.